# What does the process /usr/libexec/packagekitd do?

Tags: fedora, background-process, bandwidth

This process keeps hogging my bandwidth:

1. What does this process do?
2. Is it safe to kill it?
3. Is is safe to
   remove the package as a whole( to prevent it from starting up ever
   again)
4. Or should I just prevent it from automatically running in the background again?

I am running Fedora 23.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Please use a Search Engine to find out what it is first: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/PackageKit/pk-intro.html

Comment: So it basically runs sudo dnf update in the background? Is there any way to disable the same? Because I like to have control on the updates.

Comment: Is it a frontend to `dnf`, or a completely independent package update system? Does it cache in a separate folder?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

PackageKit is being run by GNOME Software. It's not doing automatic updates, but it is downloading them so they're ready. There is work on making this be smarter, including not doing it over bandwidth-constrained connections, but it hasn't landed yet. In the meantime, you can disable this by running:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/software/download-updates false
```

or by using the GUI dconf editor and unchecking the download-updates box under `org > gnome > software`:

[image: dconf editor gui]

Note that this is per-user. For changing the default for everyone, [see the GNOME docs](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-custom-defaults.html.en).

Comment: I use `dnf` on the terminal to update my package. Is `packagekitd` redundant? Do they "cache" their packages on the same location, or if I use one can I stop using the other?

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy  `packagekitd` is an unnecessary resource hog and is redundant if one uses `dnf`. It is one those things invented to make the UX better and not make the user think about updates and such, but it ends up frustrating the user.

Comment: Can someone elaborate on how packagekitd is redundant if dnf is there? Does dnf automatically update GNOME software?

Comment: @Cheetaiean It _can_ automatically update rpm-based gnome software. I think a lot of folks do it by hand periodically as a habit, rather than automatically. You'll also need to run flatpak update from the command line if you use those.

Answer (score 5):

- Kernel : GNU/Linux
- ProductName: Fedora
- ProductVersion: 35

#### Shutting Down PackageKitD for *Fedora >=34*

```bsh
dconf write /org/gnome/software/download-updates false
sudo systemctl stop packagekit.service
sudo systemctl disable packagekit.service
```

##### Side Effects

I used the above instructions to shut down packagekitd permanently and conserve CPU, RAM and Network usage. My laptop fan went demonstrably silent after I shut down `packagekitd`.

#### Removing PackageKit

Despite disabling the `packagekit.service` there is a possibility that the service somehow restarts itself. It is better to uninstall packagekit using the following command

```bsh
dnf remove -y PackageKit
```